# How to pass newly creating resource id's from Terraform to AWS Lambda API serverless template file

Tags: templates, terraform, output, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I am looking for some examples with code as to how to pass newly created resource id's(e.g., VPC ID, Subnet Id, etc ) from Terraform to AWS Lambda serverless template file or Cloudformation template.
One option I am thinking is to store these newly created resource id's in a common folder on AWS and let other teams access these stored resource id into their serverless templates.
Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks Prakash

Comment: Sorry, but asking for examples is out of scope of SO. Please try writing any code, and then make new question with the specific programming issues that you have. There could be many possible ways to achieve your goal, and a single precise answer can't be given.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. I agree there could be many possible ways to achieve my goal. I meant to have some references to websites that I can leverage where they already accomplished similar tasks.

Comment: If you're using cloudformation templates, you can use the outputs (if exported) of a template that can be imported by another template. If you need examples, I suggest searching in the AWS developer guides.